# Shiny works fine on localhost but not from remote host, where re is shiny-server.conf on a Windows?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

After updating R from 3.0.2 to 3.0.3 and updating the shiny package the applications I wrote are no longer accessible from remote hosts.  They work fine when accessed from machine they are running on using `http://localhost:8101`.  The host OS is Windows Server 2008R2.

I have the feeling that there is a setting a config file that is disallowing access from remote hosts.  Where is shiny-server.conf on Windows?  I searched for it but could not find it.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it might help to show the errors you're getting (client and/or server).

Answer (score 1):

you could run app using host parameter:

```
runApp("you_app", host="0.0.0.0")
```

and it should be vailable from outside (if there is not any firewall/apache/proxy etc)

Default value for host is 127.0.0.1.